# Search data in datagridview using datagridview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

User must input value in Datagridview1 "Column1", then they will get result in Datagridview2 which connected with access database after click Button1.

This is the code I tried:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Cyclecount_db_appDataSet.Query1.Select("Tracking like'" & DataGridView2.TextLength & "'")
End Sub
```

`.TextLength` >>> I use this correct when it is Textbox control

[image: Review picture]

Comment: Why would you use a DataGridView to capture text user input? Just use a TextBox for the search criteria.

Comment: @HardCode You're right. I found out that using Textbox or Richtextbox is better than use datagridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to leave this as a comment but it ended up looking too confusing that way.

Your small code snippet there seems to be trying to do the opposite of what you described so I'm going to assume that you just mistyped what you're datagridviews are named.

right now your code is trying to set the dataset for datagridview1 with a query that is looking for values that are like the length of your datagridview2.

You probably want to search for the actual value in your datagridview2 (input dgv) and I assume you went this route so you can have multiple search items

With those assumptions I'd look at doing something a little bit more like this (I'd add some error handling in here as well):

First a filter builder function

```
Private Function FilterBuilder(ByVal DGV as DataGridView) as string
Dim returnstring as string = ""
for i = 0 to DGV.Rows.Count
if returnstring = "" then 'first item we won't need a leading 'OR'
returnstring = "Tracking LIKE '" & DGV.rows(i).cells(0).value & "'"
else
returnstring += " OR Tracking LIKE '" & DGV.rows(i).cells(0).value & "'"
end if
next
return returnstring
end function
```

Now in your button click event you can call:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = Cyclecount_db_appDataSet.Query1.Select(FilterBuilder(DataGridView2))
```

Comment: Whao, thank you, it's fit perfectly well
. I just have some error with the "else" statement
. But after I put it in comment, it show the correct result

Comment: I have a typo in my answer I'll edit it but i have "Tacking" instead of "Tracking" in the Else.

Correct that and it should allow you have multiple rows in your input DGV

Comment: @ThangDang Please upvote any answer which helps, and don't forget to use the "checkmark" to mark as solved when an answer solves your initial problem.

Comment: Questions for @ThangDang, @Veegore: is there a requirement to filter on multiple criteria, even though the original question never mentions it? aren't you filtering on [Tracking] LIKE the text *length* and not the *value* such as this question (further, how can Veegore assume this? unless I missed something..., even further quoting this *DataGridView2.TextLength >>> I use this correct when it is Richtextbox control* it seems length *is* right), lastly what is the point of using [LIKE] with no wildcard instead of the standard `=`?

Comment: The reason I ask my questions is that if you do only need one filter criteria, and you do in fact need the value, not the text length, then this answer is over-complicated and the missing information linking the question and answer make this Q&A not useful future visitors.

Comment: The requirement for multiple search criteria was assumed because his input is a dgv instead of just an input/text box - the thought of multiples seemed pretty apparent given the tools he was using as input.  Using value instead of textlength I assumed was part of his issue.  The Like I left in, I have no idea what the rest of his query looks like but yes it could be changed to '='.

Comment: This is what I assumed the application was suppose to function: User enters a [series] of tracking numbers then hits the button, the database is queried and returns the results into the other datagridview.

Comment: @laancelot - no can do, it's not my question

Comment: @ThangDang Hit the checkmark to mark this as solved.

Comment: @laancelot Ok I did it, I also edit "...TextLength >>> I use this correct when it is Textbox control" so other will not too confusing with my question

Comment: @ThangDang Thanks! Good luck on your projects!